# Considering performance is it good to use spring @value in struts actions

Tags: spring, performance, struts2, struts2-spring-plugin

In an struts 2 (with spring plugin) + spring 4 ....

One can use spring `@value` in the actions to read property files (formally know as `property-placeholder`). We use this feature a lot to get our application configuration items from property files. A sample code is like:

```
@Value("#{'${City.Names}'.split(',')}") 
private List<String> cityNames;

#In the spring property files
CityNames=Tehran,Isfahan
```

On the other hand, the Struts 2 Action objects are instantiated for each request (as mentioned in https://struts.apache.org/docs/comparing-struts-1-and-2.html)

So it means that the spring always make a new action which cause that the spring run the spring EL `${City.Names}'.split(',')` for every request. So considering the performance, using `@value` in action is not a good approach.

Is it correct ?! If it is not, then how does it handled ?!

Please consider that in the real case some of our spring EL s are complicated and time consuming..

Comment: Why not to pull `@Value`-s to some singleton and inject this singleton to actions?

Comment: Yes we can use it! But I wonder if we have to and if the spring EL is running every time ?!

Comment: You didn't use this annotation in the action class, right? Or you want to use it in action classes too?

Comment: We are using this annotation in the class and it works fine, our only consideration is performance.